# How to implement stopwatch in asp.net 2.0 page 

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I want a stop watch with a start button and a stop button in my asp.net 2.0 page. How to implement this?

I would also like a timer to calculate how much time user is viewing the page so that I can add this time in my database.

Comment: a stop watch to calculate how much time user is viewing the page

Comment: I believe what you want is Google Analytics

Comment: yes similar to that but i can't use Google Analytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't tell us much. Here are a couple....

[JQuery Stopwatch Plugin](http://www.kellishaver.com/projects/stopwatch/)

[Another JQuery stopwatch plugin](http://webpages.cs.luc.edu/~laufer/424/StopwatchJQuery/)